# Laravel Update from 5.1 to >=5.5

Tags: laravel

I am trying to update my current `Laravel version(5.1)`, but unable to update.

Can anyone please help me to update `Laravel` version from `5.1` to `5.5`, `6.0`?

Answer (score 1):

Your question is not very specific. Where are your problems exactly?

In general, you need to follow the specific tasks to upgrade. Laravel has created one page for each upgrade (5.1 to 5.2, 5.2 to 5.3...)
On these pages the steps are described and also what changes has been implemented to the code.
I would upgrade version to version and have a look at the changes in the code.

Upgrade to 5.2:
https://laravel.com/docs/5.2/upgrade

to 5.3:
https://laravel.com/docs/5.3/upgrade

to 5.4:
https://laravel.com/docs/5.4/upgrade

to 5.5:
https://laravel.com/docs/5.5/upgrade

to 6:
https://laravel.com/docs/6.x/upgrade

Answer (score 0):

Update your composer.json file with the desired version of laravel. Also, check if your desired version requires a specific PHP version to run it.

```
"require": {
    "php": "^7.0",
    "laravel/framework": "5.5.*",
 },
```

Now, delete your vendor folder and composer.lock file inside your project folder.

Here is the [Laravel Upgrade Guide](https://laravel.com/docs/7.x/upgrade) where you can verify the functions that need to be updated at the code level. If you are upgrading, then you need to add the listed updated functions of the higher version from the guide. And if downgrading, you need to remove the updated functions from your code if you have used any from the higher version.

Then, run the following command inside your project folder:

`composer install`

also, you can do it with this command:

`composer update --no-scripts`

this will upgrade to the latest one.